# Connecting SVN from Remote Server

Tags: ftp, remote, svn

I have hosted my repository in assebbla & it works fine. now I want to write a script that can automate the build process : 
1. Take the code from assembla repository
2. Make a dump and copy it onto my web server.

what I have researched from net states that use of commands like 
svn co svn+ssh://username@your.remote-server.com/home/svn/test

I believe I need to open Shell on my server and type these commands but shell has been disabled from my server admin. I tried to run the same from php using exec , admin has disabled that too. (am using shared hosting and want to do a automated deployment using these simple steps. i don't want to bring my local system in this process)

now am not sure even if I get the shell access open to my server these commands like svn will work there as I don't have SVN installed on my server (its installed on assembla).

kindly let me know if any more explanation is required regarding the same or if am going on the wrong track.

Am a newbie so please be descriptive in answering :)
Thanx in advance
Ace

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to get subversion from your webhost server without shell access, it's nearly impossible.

You can choose:

1. Switch to a webhost provider which provides shell access, and if there's no svn command( most web hosting provider will have this command on their server), compile it from source.
2. Switch to a VPS with root access so you can do everything you want
3. Just use your PC as a proxy. You can run `svn checkout`, then `tar` the directory and POST or PUT it to your webhost server( using `curl` ).

Answer (score 0):

For that, you would need to get a Virtual Private Server (VPS), then you could run shell commands on it.

If you were to get shell access on your shared web host, you would need to install Subversion (on a Debian based OS like Ubuntu it would be: apt-get install subversion).

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your access method is svn+ssh://? it could be over http://

try running svn co http://< your assembla auth + url >

If you don't have shell access on your web server, it is going to be borderline impossible to download your source code, let alone setup of automated build process.

The next step for you, would be to get a web server that actually has a shell and go from there.